# How to get width of an element in react native?

Tags: react-native

How get width of an element in react native such as View ?
As there is not percent usage for width in react native, how to get width of an element or parent element?

Answer (score 18):

You can call the `onLayout` event to measure an element:

```js
measureView(event) {
  console.log('event properties: ', event);
  console.log('width: ', event.nativeEvent.layout.width)
}

<View onLayout={(event) => this.measureView(event)}>
```

As far as percentage width and height, you can get the window width and height and use them like this:

```js
const {
    ...
    Dimensions
} = React

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height

// 80% width
width: width * .8,

// 25% height
height: height / 4,
```

Comment: Be aware that `onLayout` event will be triggered **after** the component was rendered. So if you want percentage width of chlld components without re-render I can suggest using variables as described [here](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#percents)