# How to get the size of a React Native View Dynamically without rendering?

Tags: react-native

[I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246207/4370279) that [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) param can be used to get the dimensions allocated to render the `View`. But in my case, I need to get the dimensions without rendering the view. Is it possible ?

I tried the web,no one talked about it.

Edit:

**Use case**

I am trying to create a `TableView`.Instead of passing the `columnWidth` manually into the component, I am trying to get the width of the longest text and calculate the dimension to render it , and set it as the `columnWidth` . So that no cell would be shrunken.

Comment: Any solution for that?